Inductor selection for a buck converter with uncertain output current
I'm struggling to choose the correct value inductor for my design with a TPS54331. Based on my estimations, I calculated a DC current consumption of 1.3 A for my circuit, but sometimes the circuit might draw a higher current consumption up to 2.2 A for a couple of seconds (like when activating the audio amplifier to sound an alarm). It's important to keep the output voltage ripple low. So based on which current (nominal or maximum), should I calculate my inductor value to keep the ripple down when drawing nominal and maximum current?

What are the worst-case input and output voltage ranges?

"A couple seconds" is a long time as far as thermals and sat current etc., so you should design your converter for the higher output current.

The input supply is a sealed acid battery. So something between 14.2v and 11.5v is expected for the input. The output is a fixed 5v that powers a STM32 MCU through an LDO (TPS7A8101). The maximum input for the LDO 7 volts. So the voltage transients must be limited to meet the requirements of the design. (Not exceeding the absolute max ratings of the LDO and not triggering an MCU reset.)
